# FactoryGirl: Creating a User that requires a Program to already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my application, for a user to be created, a Program needs to already exist. When the user is created, they are assigned a program that matches the user attributes. If no appropriate program exists, and Exception is raised, so I'm trying to figure out how to create a program so my user can be created.

Right now I'm doing this in my tests:

```
  subject(:user) do
    Program.create!(name: 'test', gender: 'Female', goal_id: '1', experience_id: '1')
    User.create!(email: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678', password_confirmation: '12345678', goal_id: '1', experience_level_id: '1', gender: 'Female')
  end
```

but I want to create a Factory instead, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email                               'test@test.com'
    password                            '12345678'
    password_confirmation               '12345678'
    goal_id                             1
    experience_level_id                 1
    gender                              'Female'
  end
end
```

Using FactoryGirl, how do I create a User if that user needs a Program to exist already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want.

In your test:

```
 program = FactoryGirl.create(:program)
 user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, 
   :goal_id => program.goal_id,
   :gender => program.gender,
   :experience_level_id => program.experience_id
)
```

In your factory:

```
factory :program do
  gender "Female"
  goal_id '1'
  experience_id '1'
  name 'test'
end
factory :user do
  # other attributes
end
```

**Update:** If you always want to set up users this way, you might do something like this in your factory:

```
factory :user do
  # other attributes
  after(:build) do |user|
    program = build(:program)
    user.goal_id = program.goal_id
    user.gender = program.gender
    user.experience_level_id = program.experience_id
  end
end
```

If you only want the default in some tests, you might want to rename the factory to something like user_with_default_program, and have it inherit from the main user factory. If you go through the docs at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md you should be able to slim things down for your use case.

Comment: That works! Any idea how to compact that all down so I only have to call user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) instead of having to call both user and program in the test itself?

Comment: Hope the update points you in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: @Arel - You can do whatever you want in the `after_create` block, including looking up information in the programs table and using that to populate the user fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an [association](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations):

```
  factory :user
    email                 "email@test.com"
    password              "12345678"
    password_confirmation "12345678"
    goal_id               1
    experience_level_id   1
    gender                "Female"
    association           :program
  end
```

Comment: Doing that results in an error ``method_missing': undefined method `program=' for #<User:` Any idea why? I do have a `programs.rb` factory

Comment: @Arel This approach works if you have a `:program` factory and an association between `User` and `Program`.

Comment: Ok, a user has many programs through user_programs. Is that why this method isn't working for me? Does it have to be a simple belongs_to/has_many association?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `User` factory find or create a `Program` as part of the creation process and set the `User` fields appropriately prior to saving. What is the relationship between `User` and `Program`?  It's not obvious from your code.

Comment: A user has many user_programs. A user is assigned a program in a `before_create` callback. All programs are pre-existing, so a user just gets assigned a program when created.

Comment: So is there a `program_id` field in `User`?

Comment: No, there is a user_programs table that keeps track of all past programs a user has been assigned.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you mean by "a user is assigned a program". How is that "assignment" represented? Are you just talking about populating some of the user fields (e.g. `gender`, `goal_id`) with their corresponding values from one of the programs? If so, how is that "assigning a program"?

Comment: A user `has_many :programs, through: :user_programs` so when a user is created, in a `before_create` callback, the first `user_program` record is created for the user in the `user_programs` join table. Does that make sense?